# Can I travel to Germany with an expired visa and renew it in Germany?

Tags: visas

I have an expired Schengen Visa. Can I travel to Germany with it and then just renew it when I arrive there? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot (unless you are a citizen of a country whose citizens enjoy visa-free entry into the Schengen area, which I presume you are not).  If you require a visa to enter the Schengen area, you must have a *valid* visa before boarding your flight to the Schengen area.

Comment: Nitpick just for fun: valid visa *on arrival*. They can board a few hours before as long as the visa will be valid when they land

Comment: ...and a valid visa on departure as well (as long as we are nitpicking).

Comment: @ArjunaDeva you're using the wrong terminology, as explained in the comments to your [identical question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178322/19400).  Please engage with the commenters there.  This will likely lead to a better understanding of the process.